# How to create a display value for a radio

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

```
<input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" value="blue">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" value="red">Red<br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayFunction()">Display</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

```
function displayFunction() {
   if document.getElementById(color1).checked) {
      color_value = document.getElementById(color1).value;
   } else if (document.getElementById('color2).checked) { 
      color_value= document.getElementById('color2 ').value
   }
```

I am trying to display the value of the selected radio button, but I am not sure why it isn't working? and when it does work it disables my other buttons

```
<input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" value="blue">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" value="red">Red<br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayFunction()">Display</button>
<div id="display"></div> 

function displayFunction() {
   if document.getElementById(color1).checked) {
      color_value = document.getElementById(color1).value;
   } else if (document.getElementById('color2).checked) { 
      color_value= document.getElementById('color2 ').value
   }

I tried this, but it is displaying the javascript on the page. Any suggestions?
```

Comment: Post both your HTML and JavaScript,  that way it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: use title attribute

Comment: function displayFunction() {
        if
    document.getElementById(color1).checked) {
        color_value = 
    document.getElementById(color1).value;
        }else
    if(document.getElementById('color2).checked)
    { 
        color_value=
    document.getElementById('color2').value
    }

Comment: what is a title attribute?

Comment: relevant code must be included in the question itself, not as comment

Comment: `document.getElementById(color1)` is wrong. The correct one is `document.getElementById("color1")` with quotes.

Comment: thank you cadu I will try that!

Comment: sorry, still new to all of this

Comment: https://github.com/RachelSchmitz/L-A-458-558/blob/master/assignment1/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function displayFunction()
{
   if(document.getElementById('color1').checked)
   {
     document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById('color1').value;
   }

   else if(document.getElementById('color2').checked)
   {
     document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById('color2').value;
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById('color1').value`

Comment: Thanks. Must have missed that.

Comment: I will try this!!

Comment: I noticed in your git repo that you do not have your function between <script></script> tags. Put it between those and it should work

Comment: @RSchmitz, if you are satisfied, would you please upvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```js
theForm.oninput =()=> {
  displayColor.textContent = theForm.colorN.value
}
```

```css
label,
div {
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  clear: both; 
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form id="theForm">

  <label title="Blue"><input type="radio" name="colorN" value="blue">Blue</label>

  <label title="Red"><input type="radio" name="colorN" value="red">Red</label>

</form>

<div id="displayColor">x</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function displayFunction() {
   var color_value = "";
   if(document.getElementById("color1").checked) {
  color_value = document.getElementById("color1").value;
   } else if (document.getElementById("color2").checked) { 
  color_value= document.getElementById('color2').value;
   }
  console.log(color_value);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" value="blue">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" value="red">Red<br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayFunction()">Display</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```